# PHP, LDAP page redirect

Tags: php, redirect, ldap, html

I am a novice and I am working on a php project where i would like to redirect users to specific page after logging in based on the Organizational Unit they belong to in the Active Directory. See code snippet below:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

        $ldaphost = "ldapServer"; 
        $ldapport = ldap port number; 

        // Connecting to LDAP
        $ldap = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
        or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");


        $auth_user =$_POST['username'];
        $auth_pass =$_POST['password'];


         ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
         ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        @$bind = ldap_bind($ldap, 'mydomain\\'.$auth_user , $auth_pass);



    if ($bind) {



        $samaccountname = $auth_user;

        $filter="(samaccountname=$samaccountname)";
        $dn="DC=mydomain, DC=com"; 

        $res = ldap_search($ldap, $dn, $filter);
        $first = ldap_first_entry($ldap, $res);
        $data = ldap_get_dn($ldap, $first);



        echo "Dn is: ".$data;


    } else {
        $msg = "Invalid email address / password";
        echo $msg;
    }

}else{
?>
    <form action="TestGroup.php" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Username: </label><input id="username" type="text" name="username" /> 
        <label for="password">Password: </label><input id="password" type="password" name="password" />        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is include a subsequent file after a correct or incorrent login attempt.

For example:

```
if ($bind) {
    //some code
    include('login_success.php'); 
    //or: include('page_to_user_OU_page.php');
}
else {
    include('login_failed.php'); 
    exit();
}
```

This solution is flexible, you can change it to your specific needs.

Comment: Can you kindly help me with the sample code of what is intended to be in the 'page_to_user_OU_page.php